# How do I update kubernetes deployment image and command?

Tags: deployment, kubernetes, kubectl

I see that I can use the "kubectl set image" command to update a container used in a deployment, like this:

```
kubectl set image deployment/myapp myapp=repo.mycompany.com/myapp/ui:beta.119
```

But, i would also like to use a different startup command in some situations. Is there a way to update both the image AND the command used for the container?

Comment: U can easily do `kubectl edit` which will open yaml in editor. On saving the file which apply the changes

Comment: Thanks, but I don't mean manually. I need some command that I can run from Bamboo.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `kubectl patch` for that. Run `kubectl patch --help` to get the docs, but as far as I can tell something like this should do it:

```
$ kubectl patch deployment <your-deployment> -p '
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: <container-name>
          command: ["new", "command"]
'
```

Comment: I went with the yaml notation in this example to make it more readable, but multiline command are not that cool, when it comes to programmatic approach. You can use json of course if you wan't